# Should I use a HMT association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have an application with a text model, a photo model, a video model and ultimately a Blog model.

Users can create blogs that have text, photos, and video content. All of these different forms of content can be implemented on each blog. So each blog post can have a mix of photos, videos, text etc...

What's the best way to setup the associations in this case?

I'd like to set it up the best possible way to begin with so I don't have to worry about changing it down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd prefer in such case to use STI models.

Create a Post model, and Text, Photo, Video will inherit it.

Here is more detail manual about STI: http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/

In such case your blog will

```
has_many :posts
```

Comment: ah this is great! looking into it more thanks for sharing.

Comment: and a user belongs_to the blog? or the post? or both?

Comment: It depends of your requirements. If only one user posts to blog then "blog belongs to user, post belongs to blog". In other case, when blog has multiple users, then "user belongs_to blog, post belongs to blog and post belongs to user".

Comment: I just thought of this, but couldn't the tes, photo and video's just be columns on the post table instead of seperate tables?